# Azure Computer Vision not running despite S1 pricing tier

Tags: azure, azure-devops, computer-vision, cloud, azure-cognitive-services

I get this error when I try to run a code utilizing Azure Computer Vision.

```
azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision.models._models_py3.ComputerVisionErrorResponseException: 
    (429) Requests to the Analyze Image Operation under Computer Vision API (v3.2) have exceeded rate limit of your current ComputerVision S1 pricing tier. Please retry after 1 second. 
    Please contact Azure support service if you would like to further increase the default rate limit.
```

According to this, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/cognitive-services/computer-vision/, the S1 tier allows 10 transactions per second. Even after several minutes of inactivity, I get the same error. What am I missing out? What is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the [analyze image API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/computer-vision-v3-2/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499f21b/console), we are able to see response as shown below.

Here is quick-start [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-quickstart-code/tree/master/python/ComputerVision) using SDK and REST API.

[image]